# Access network share from Store app

Tags: c#, networking, windows-8, microsoft-metro

StreamReader and HttpClient can't access network share path. Is it possible to access a file on LAN network from  Windows Store app?

Comment: Yes it's possible.. do you have code that you can show as to how you are trying to access it it also sounds like a permissions issue as well
here is a Link that you can access to get you started with many different things that you can do in regards to accessing Storage Folders http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Comment: Checkout this link as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A Windows Store app has two ways to access a network file:

1. [Use HomeGroup to access the pictures, music, and videos libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150593.aspx). As long as you have declared the capabilities, you can perform this without user input. But it is limited to these libraries. You can also access the documents library, but it is heavily policed in the store certification.
2. [Use the FilePicker to ask the user to pick the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771180.aspx). This requires user input but allows access to any file that the user can access.

The article [Quickstart: Accessing HomeGroup content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ218967.aspx) has a few more variations of these options.